# How to make a QR Code in Python if I have the Encoding Bits?

Tags: python, qr-code

I am working on a project where I have to edit the encoded bits of a QR code. I generated the QR code using the pyqrcode library in Python and then used the .text() function to convert it into a String.

After that, I made a list out of this String.

Now, I have to make modifications in this list (according to my algorithm) and then make a QR code again.

How can this be done? Any ideas?

Here is a sample code.

```
import pyqrcode
import png
import PIL
big_code = pyqrcode.create('q', error='H', version=2)
big_code.png('qr.png')
a = big_code.text(quiet_zone=0)
x1 = []
li1 = a.split('\n')
for i in li1:
    x1.append([j for j in i])
print(x1)
```

The data in the x1 variable is what I want to be converted to a QR Code.

Basically, I have the encoding bits and I have to generate a new QR Code in python.

I hope I was able to explain the problem properly.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO! I do not know the package `pyqrcode`. How does the resulting text look like? Is it a series of "0" and "1" encoded in ASCII?

Comment: @SvenKrüger Yes, the resulting string after the use of .text() function is a series of 0s and 1s.

Comment: You can check the output here https://pastebin.com/XJAPkfur
Documentation for pyqrcode - https://github.com/mnooner256/pyqrcode